# Как переписать этот код на чистый JS?

Tags: javascript

```
$('.click').on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.body').height()
    })
})
```

Comment: Как? Не использовать jquery, в чем у Вас трудности?

Comment: Простите , тут на что нажатие происходит? `$('.click').`

Comment: @UladzimirCharniauski, подозреваю, что на элемент с классом "click"

Answer (score 0):

Может вот это ? Кликните на зеленый блок чтобы подвинуть его.

```
<script>
    slidingDiv = document.getElementById('lol');
    slidingDiv.addEventListener('click', slideDivDown);

    function slideDivDown ()
    {
        this.style.marginTop = '100px';
    }
</script>
```

демо: https://jsfiddle.net/gbarkovalev/onab9k4z/

Comment: уже давно в js есть querySelector...

Comment: если так то измени одну строчку slidingDiv = document.querySelector('.lol');